# how to set focus to the angularjs-dropdown-multiselect?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs-dropdown-multiselect for the selection of multiple.And i want to set focus to the dropdown. For the remaining controls in my form i am using

" document.getElementById("Select").focus();"

but for dropdown it is not getting.How can i do that. Somebody please help me.

my html div for dropdown:

```
 <div style=" width:157%;height:120%" id="SectionSelect" ng-click="clicked()" ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="sectiondata" selected-model="sectionmodel" extra-settings="sectionsettings"></div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I think it should be `document.getElementById("SectionSelect").focus();`

Comment: thanks prince ,that also i tried but it is not working.